# How to restart and rebuild node app with pm2 in production without downtime?

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2

I have node application on `nginx` with `pm2`. I have my domain for ex. `domain.com` with A record `11.11.11.11`.

When I make changes in my code daily, I need to update app. To update app, I need to rebuild app(with `npm run build)` and then start app(`npm run start`) again which takes like 10-15mins. I wanted to do restart app without downtime.

How can I restart app with any downtime?

Comment: Do you mean with no downtime, or without the build step? The only way to have *no* downtime is to have two servers; build one and start it, then build the other.

Comment: Downtime means, my website is down for approx. 15minutes when building and starting app

Comment: If I use 2 servers, how can I do that?

Comment: Same way you do it now, but twice, and front it with a load-balancer/fail-over mechanism that allows you to point it at a single server. Google for "rolling update" or similar.  But what I asked is *no* downtime, or *less* downtime?

Comment: can't you build the app while the old version is still running?